# Find minimum distances between rows of two matrices

Tags: r, distance, lapply

I have two tables, X and Y, (X is big and Y has 9 rows, of course same columns) and I need to find the minimum euclidean distance between each row of X with each row of Y. 
I do this and it works:

```
x<-matrix(c(3,6,3,4,8),nrow=5,ncol=7,byrow = TRUE)     
y<-matrix(c(1,4,4,1,9),nrow=5,ncol=7,byrow = TRUE)

unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(y)), function(i) min(sqrt(colSums((y[i, ] -t(x))^2))))
```

Now I need to export which row of Y (1 to 9) is the one for each row, and there is my problem, because I do not know how to face this. Any clue about how to write this?
    I've been thinking about doing something like:

```
unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(y)), function(i) nrow(min(sqrt(colSums((y[i, ] - t(x))^2)))==T)))
```

but I cannot make it work.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What do you want the output to look like?  Please edit your question and provide a few rows of what you think the correct output should be.  Also, I'm confused about A and B versus x and y.

Comment: also, see `?which.min`

Comment: I finally made it work by using which.min, and now the solution is fast and easy. 
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: you can refer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847196/distance-calculation-on-large-vectors-performance/33409695#33409695) where I provided different methods w/ high performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with my [imputation](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputation) package:

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++0x") # needed for the lambda functions in Rcpp

# install/load package, create example data
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/imputation")
library(imputation)
set.seed(123)
a <- matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol= 10)
b <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)

# which row of a is closest to each row of b
apply(b, 1, function(i, a) {
  which.min(imputation:::dist_q.matrix(rbind(i, a), ref= 1L, q=2))
}, a= a)
[1] 471 502 555 969 692 757 116 913 556 566

# which row of b is closest to each row of a
apply(a, 1, function(i, b) {
  which.min(imputation:::dist_q.matrix(rbind(i, b), ref= 1L, q=2))
}, b= b)
### result not shown since it's large
```

Technically, you don't need the arguments `ref` and `q` since `1L` and `2` are the defaults.