# Calculate Distance using Latitude and Longitude data in Different Data frames of different lengths with loop

Tags: r, loops, distance, latitude-longitude, geosphere

I have 2 data frames of different lengths, each with a longitude and latitude coordinate. I would like to connect the two data frames by calculating the distance between the lat/long points.

For simplicity, Data frame A (starting point) has the following structure

```
ID     long      lat 
1 -89.92702 44.19367 
2 -89.92525 44.19654 
3 -89.92365 44.19756 
4 -89.91949 44.19848 
5 -89.91359 44.19818
```

And Data frame B (end point) has a similar structure but shorter

```
ID      LAT       LON
1  43.06519 -87.91446
2  43.14490 -88.07172
3  43.08969 -87.91202
```

I would like to calculate the distance between each point such that I would end with a data frame, merged to A, that has the distances between A1 and B1, A1 and B2, A1 and B3. Furthermore, this should repeat for all values of A in A$ID with all values of B$ID

```
A$ID   B$ID
1      1
2      2
3      3
4
5
```

Prior to posting this, I consulted several Stack Overflow threads (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198665/r-calculate-distance-based-on-latitude-longitude-from-two-data-frames) and [This Medium post](https://blog.exploratory.io/calculating-distances-between-two-geo-coded-locations-358e65fcafae) but I am not sure how to approach the looping, especially since the lists are of different lengths.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using two packages: `sf` and `tidyverse`. The first one is used to convert the data into simple features and calculate the distance; while, the second one is used to put the data in the desired format.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# Transform data into simple features
sfA <- st_as_sf(A, coords = c("long","lat"))
sfB <- st_as_sf(B, coords = c("LON","LAT"))

# Calculate distance between all entries of sf1 and sf2
distances <- st_distance(sfA, sfB, by_element = F)
# Set colnames for distances matrix
colnames(distances) <- paste0("B",1:3)

# Put the results in the desired format
# Transform distances matrix into a tibble
as_tibble(distances) %>%
  # Get row names and add them as a column
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  # Set ID as the column name for the row numbers
  rename("ID" = "rowname") %>%
  # Transform ID to numeric
  mutate_at(vars(ID), as.numeric) %>%
  # Join with the original A data frame
  right_join(A, by = "ID") %>%
  # Change the order of columns
  select(ID, long, lat, everything()) %>%
  # Put data into long format
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("B"),
               names_to = "B_ID",
               names_pattern = "B(\\d)",
               values_to = "distance")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `outer` quite succinctly here.

```
library(geosphere)
d <- outer(1:nrow(A), 1:nrow(B), Vectorize(function(x, y) distm(A[x, 2:3], B[y, 3:2])))
cbind(A, `colnames<-`(d, paste0("B", seq(nrow(B)))))
#   ID      long      lat       B1       B2       B3
# 1  1 -89.92702 44.19367 205173.6 189641.7 203652.9
# 2  2 -89.92525 44.19654 205252.6 189722.5 203728.1
# 3  3 -89.92365 44.19756 205219.0 189689.8 203692.6
# 4  4 -89.91949 44.19848 205015.6 189488.0 203486.2
# 5  5 -89.91359 44.19818 204620.0 189093.8 203087.6
```

---

*Data:*

```
A <- read.table(header=T, text="ID     long      lat 
1 -89.92702 44.19367 
2 -89.92525 44.19654 
3 -89.92365 44.19756 
4 -89.91949 44.19848 
5 -89.91359 44.19818")
B <- read.table(header=T, text="ID      LAT       LON
1  43.06519 -87.91446
2  43.14490 -88.07172
3  43.08969 -87.91202")
```